# The Bluestacks Android emulator is built using .Net?

Tags: java, android, .net, bluestacks

I recently installed the Bluestacks Android emulator. I happened to look at the process running under ProcessExplorer and was surprised to see that it is a .NET application.

[image: Process Explorer]

The `HD-Frontend.exe` is the Bluestacks UI process and is highlighted yellow because it has loaded the .NET framework. There are a number of other processes associated with Bluestacks and most are also .NET.

Opening the EXE in Reflector.NET also shows that it is .NET.

[image: Reflector.Net]

I thought Android was Java-based. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android is Java-based, but that does not mean an Android emulator has to be written in Java -- just functionally emulate Android devices.

While [BlueStack's site](http://www.bluestacks.com/app-player.html) does not list any system requirements for its emulator that I could find, at least a couple sites -- e.g. [Bazooka Apps](http://www.bazookaapps.com/downloading-and-installing-android-emulator-bluestacks/) and [Android Emulator for PC](http://www.androidemulatorforpc.com/2012/05/install-bluestacks-android-emulator-for.html) -- mention .NET as a requirement.

Ultimately the proof of what's going on is right in the process list and Reflector results you found.

Answer (score 0):

its an emulation tool whose job is to read the dex code respond to that how the android phone should respond and not to compile and run that dex so it could be on python or ruby also there is no boundation at all that you have to make android emulator on java becuase android is built upon java.